# Updating a part of the page without reloading the whole page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, mongodb, pug

I have a problem where I need to only update a part of the web page when someone adds a label and not the whole page.

pug front end:

```
  h2 Labels
    each labelName in label
      h4 #{(JSON.stringify(labelName)).substr(1).slice(41, -1).replace(/['"]+/g, '')}
  h2 Add a label 
  form(action='/labeling/#{name}/add_label', method='post', id='insertLabel')
    label(for='insertLabel ') Add label
    input(type='text', value='', name='label', id='insertLabel')
    button(type="submit") submit
```

clicking submit makes a post request which is handled in the middleware here

```
router.post('/labeling/:stream_name/add_label', function (req, res, next) {
  overallTime = '00:00:15'
  labelName = req.body.label
  db_label.insertLabel(labelName, overallTime)
  db_label.findLabels((err, labels) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.sendStatus(500)
    }
    res.redirect('/labeling/' + outputName)
})
```

insertLabel inserts labelName and overallTime into mongoDB and findLabel brings back what labels stored in the relevant collection, the result looks like this

```
[ { _id: 5a7201d8a6a06f1627ad75ba, label: 'moo: 00:00:16' },
  { _id: 5a7201e9a6a06f1627ad75bb, label: 'moo2: 00:00:26' } ]
```

but I am getting lost among all the information I am getting. In this situation, should I use Jquery/Ajax, just Ajax, Axios or vanilla Javascript?

Comment: Which part of the web page do you need to update based on the data from your labels? Is it the `h2 labels` and underlying code?

Comment: Just the h2 labels part "  h2 Labels
    each labelName in label
      h4 #{(JSON.stringify(labelName)).substr(1).slice(41, -1).replace(/['"]+/g, '')}"

Comment: You'll have to use ajax calls and update the page based on the response, or if it doesn't require a response from the server, you could use a script (JavaScript) to update the DOM.

Comment: Make sure that your controller is sending response data instead of redirecting to page or blade view.

Comment: @dasacodec I'm having a hard time translating the answers I am getting from html to pug, your comment was very helpful, i'll post an update once I resolved this issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery would be useful.

This needs to end up in the head of the page or just before the end of the page.

NOTE: I have renamed your form. You must have unique IDs!

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
  $("#insertLabelForm").on("submit",function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault(); // stop submission
    // sending all form data - you can also do { "label": $("#insertLabel").val(); 
    // instead of $(this).serialize()
    $.post(this.action,$(this).serialize(),function(data) {
      $.each(data,function(label) { // loop over result
        $("#someContainer").append(label._id+":"+label.label+"<br/>");
      });  
    });  
  });   
});
</script>
```

Comment: Would I put this under script ?

Comment: I have no experience with pug. Post rendered HTML. Your code and needs are not clear

Comment: Please see update. I had to rename the form since you have conflicting IDs

Comment: I thank mplungjan for generously donating his time to share his knowledge, this answer has solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

I assuming that you need to add newly created Label name in `#Lables` div. So I use Jquery for this.

Instead of retrieve back the all Lables result from table you can just append newly created Label name in to div.
*( this will happens if the Label is created successfully.)*

You should append your result to #Lables

```
<form id="insertLabelForm" action="/labeling/#{name}/add_label" method="post" id="insertLabel">
    <label for="insertLabel">Add label</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="label" id="insertLabel"/>
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#insertLabelForm').on('submit',function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var newLableName = $('#insertLabel').val();

            $.ajax({
                url:$('#insertLabelForm').attr('action'),
                method:"post",
                data:$('#insertLabelForm').serialize(),
                success:function () {
                    $('#Lables').append('<h4>'+newLableName+'</h4>');
                }
            })
        })
    })
</script>
```